# How to call a Firebase function from a Formik form?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I have a `LoginScreen.js` with the Formik form and a `FirebaseLogin.js` file with the logic to login users using Firebase.
How can I send the email and password values from the LoginScreen to FirebaseLogin API?

on the `LoginScreen.js` I have the following part which currently logs the email and password correctly:

```
    <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
        onSubmit={values => console.log(values)} // this logs the correct values of email and password
    >
        //.. more form code here
        <View>
            <Pressable>
                <Text onPress={handleSubmit}>Login</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    
    </Formik>
```

Then I have the Firebase API on `FirebaseLogin.js`:

```
export default function FirebaseLogin(props) {
    const email="";
    const password="";

    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in                 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
        });
   
}
```

But how can I pass the email and password from the `LoginScreen` to the `FirebaseLogin` logic?

I somehow need to pass the email and password as props, but the `FirebaseLogin.js` is not an actual React component, it's just an API function. So I can't find a way to do it

Comment: Pass the values as ...values

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps here.
Firstly you need to modify the `FirebaseLogin` function. Because it's not the react component so no need of props here. We will simply receive an object with email and password fields. and using those fields we will logged into the firebase. Your function will be looks like below.

```
export default function FirebaseLogin({email, password}) {
const auth = getAuth();
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in                 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
    });

}
```

Now import the `FirebaseLogin` method from the `FirebaseLogin.js` file into the `LoginScreen.js` component.
Now in the `LoginScreen.js` file your code will be like this.

```
    <Formik
    initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
    onSubmit={values => FirebaseLogin(values)}
>
    //.. more form code here
    <View>
        <Pressable>
            <Text onPress={handleSubmit}>Login</Text>
        </Pressable>
    </View>

</Formik>
```

Please let me know if you had any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A full working example would be:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {
 StyleSheet,
 KeyboardAvoidingView,
 TextInput,
 Button,
} from "react-native";

const UserSignInEmail = ({ email, password }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const auth = getAuth();

  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    const user = userCredential.user;
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
  });

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      navigation.replace("Dashboard");
    }
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);

return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      onSubmit={(values) => UserSignInEmail(values)}
    >
      {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
        <>
          <TextInput
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
            onBlur={handleBlur("email")}
            value={values.email}
            keyboardType="email-address"
          />
          <TextInput
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
            onBlur={handleBlur("password")}
            value={values.password}
            secureTextEntry
          />
          <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
        </>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
};

export default UserSignInEmail;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```